# Rails application as proxy for multiple rails applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have multiple rails application running at a server. Each one at one port (ex: 8001, 8002, 8003, ...).

I would like to create another rails application that will act as a proxy to the others. The proxy rails app would run for example at port 8000 of domain www.example.com and, depending on requests do:

www.example.com:8000/app1 - pass the request to the app running at port 8001

www.example.com:8000/app2 - pass the request to the app running at port 8002

www.example.com:8000/app3 - pass the request to the app running at port 8003

I know this is possible with apache but in my case apache is not an option. Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: Why don't you use nginx or apache or anything else? With Rails you'll get perfomance issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it in Application Controller or via yor `routes.rb`:

```
match "/:app", :to => redirect{ |params|
  case params[:app] 
  when "app1"
    "http://www.example.com:8001/"
  when "app2"
    "http://www.example.com:8002/"
  when "app3"
    "http://www.example.com:8003/"
  end
}
```

Comment: This works very well on rails 3. Do you know the alternative for rails 2? Thank you very much.